# Galois Theory, proving a set of hom is the same size as the galois group

Tags: galois-theory

So this is the set-up: $E/F$  is Galois with group $G$. Let $A$ be a commutative $F$ algebra such that the $E$-algebra $A\otimes_F E$ is isomorphic to the product of finitely many copies of $E$. Consider the set $X_A$ of all $F$-algebra homomorphisms $A\rightarrow E$.

I want to show: There is a natural action of $G$ on $X_A$ and $card(X_A)=\dim_F(E)$.

This is what I have.

The natural action is given by composition (that is, $(g,f)\mapsto g\circ f$ for $g\in G$ and $f\in X_A$).

For the second part I have that $\dim_F(E)=|G|$, so I wanted to find a bijection between elements of $G$ and maps, and the way I wanted to count the maps is by picking an $F$-basis for $A$ (call it $B=\{a_i\}$) and then we would have to define what $f(a_i)$ is which could be anything in $E$ . The problem Im having is that I dont know the dimension of $A$ as an $F$-vector space. I know I have to use the condition that $A\otimes_F E$ is isomorphic to finitely many copies of $E$ but I dont know where.

Any ideas on how to continue?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at Corollary, p. V29, in Bourbaki's Algebra Ch.4 to 7.
This is generally true for separable algebras.
Bourbaki first proves that set of $F-$algebra homomorphisms of $A$ in $E$ (lets denote it by $\mathcal E$) is a free subest of a vector space $Hom_F(A,E)$ over $E$. This gives us card$\mathcal E\leq [A:F]$ and equality iff $\mathcal E$ is a basis for $Hom_F(A,E)$. Here we have to use spliting of $A\otimes E$ into product of  separable extensions,